# I am validating data using Regex and I have the username and email working but the password is returning a value of null

Tags: c#, html, regex

This is my code for this and I don't understand why it isn't working I used the same template as my email and username and they both work fine.

```
string Password = Request["Password"];

System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex2 =
    new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([^0-9]*)$");
// does the string follow the regex structure?
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match2 = regex2.Match(Password);
//if yes
if (match2.Success)
{

}
else
{
    passwordAlert = "password is not valid";
}
```

```html
<form class="text-center" method="post">
    <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email"/> </label> <p>@emailAlert</p> <br />
    <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> </label> <p>@usernameAlert</p> <br />
    <label>Password: <input type="password" name="Password" /> </label> <p>@passwordAlert</p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />

</form>
```

```cs
    string emailAlert = "";
    string usernameAlert = "";
    string passwordAlert = "";

    if(IsPost)
    {

    string email = Request["email"];

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
    // does the string follow the regex structure?
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match = regex.Match(email);
    //if yes
    if (match.Success){


    } else {
        emailAlert = "email is not valid";    
    }

    string username = Request["username"];

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex1 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.-]*$");
    // does the string follow the regex structure?
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match1 = regex1.Match(username);
    //if yes
    if (match1.Success)
    {


    }
    else
    {
        usernameAlert = "username is not valid";
    }    

}

    string Password = Request.Form["Password"];

    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex2 = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^([0-9],{6,})$");
    // does the string follow the regex structure?
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match2 = regex2.Match(Password);
    //if yes
    if (match2.Success)
    {


    }
    else
    {
        passwordAlert = "password is not valid";
    }

}
```

```html
<form runat="server" class="text-center" method="post">
      <label>Email: <input type="text" name="email"/> </label> <p>@emailAlert</p> <br />
      <label>Username: <input type="text" name="username" /> </label> <p>@usernameAlert</p> <br />
      <label>Password: <input Request.Form["Password"]; type="password" name="Password" /> </label> <p>@passwordAlert</p>
      <input type="submit" name="Submit" />


</form>
```

I have added the full code now just in case there is a conflict before the point of error

thanks in advance

Comment: What is the password that is failing?

Comment: Use `@"^[^0-9]*$"`. Do not use regex delimiters in C#. Does it work if you remove the `/../`?

Comment: When compiling the webpage throws an error "Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: input" the "Request.Form["password"]" didn't fix it

Comment: it doesn't work when the forward slashes are removed

Comment: Ok, please correct this typo in the question.

Comment: i've ammended the //

Comment: The `ArgumentNullException` is thrown by `Regex.Match(string input)`, meaning `Password` is `null`.

Comment: Your regex means: any text not containing digits, including zero-length texts. What do you consider as a valid password?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your regular expression from this
`^([^0-9]*)$` to this `^([0-9]*)$`

You also need to use to read password field

```
Request.Form["Password"];
```

In form tag add runat=Server

Comment: Please explain why OP needs to remove the leading `^`.

Comment: Otherwise the pattern do not make any sense. By removing ^ atleast it show that password should contain numbers only.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your answer and explain why it "does not make any sense"? I think your suggested pattern doesn't make any sense, because `([0-9]*)$` will match any string.

Comment: `[^0-9]*` matches any string **not** containing digits, including zero length strings. `[0-9]*` matches strings containing only digits, including zero length strings. The `*` is clearly wrong and should be replaced by `+` or better `{6,}` by specifying a minimum length. Whether the password should contain only digits or only non-digits is not clear, as the OP doesn't specify it.

Comment: it is still stating that the value = null

Comment: In regex for password instead of ^([0-9],{6,})$  try ^[0-9]{6,}$

Comment: nope the problem is with this line System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match2 = regex2.Match(Password);